# Angular4 *ngIf not working / Variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular-ng-if

I am trying to get in my *view* details of a chosen item. It seems like the ***ngIf** statement doesn't work. It renders a plain page instead of "details" of a chosen "person".
For testing purposes I exchanged the ***ngIf** statement into a true one `*ngIf="1"`, then I managed to get the page markup rendered (it worked!), but

```
{{ person.name }} and `{{ person.id }}`
```

didn't work. 
So, it looks like my **details.html** knows nothing about **person** variable.

What should be done to get the **details.html** component rendered correctly?

**person.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { IPerson } from '../persons/person';

@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
  private _personUrl = './assets/persons.json';

  constructor(private _http:Http){}

  getPersons(): Observable<IPerson[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._personUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => <IPerson[]>response.json().personsData)
  }

   getPerson(id:number): Observable<IPerson>{
    return this.getPersons()
    .map(persons => persons.find(person => person.id === id));
  }
```

}

**details.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="person" class="container">
  <h3>Person Details</h3>
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <div>{{ person.name }}</div>
     <div>{{ person.id }}</div>
  </div>

  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

**details.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { PersonService } from '../service/person.service';
import { IPerson } from '../persons/person';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-details',
   templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css'] 
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public person: IPerson;

  constructor(
    private _PersonService: PersonService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        let id = +params['id'];
        this._PersonService.getPerson(id)
    .map(person => this.person = person).subscribe();
    })
  }


}
```

**persons.json**

```
{
  "personsData" : [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "KC"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "KN"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "DG"
    }]
 }
```

**UPD** 
It seems the problem is the **person** variable in `details.component.ts` which is undefined, although I declared it in the exported class.

Comment: Is the name of your html file *details.component.html*, or *details.html*? This is a little confusing. You have **details.html** all over the place, but `details.component.html` in the component code.

Comment: @R.Richards Sorry for making you confused. It is actually details.component.html, just wrote so to shorten the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `params` property of the `ActivatedRoute` returns an observable which you need to subscribe to. So we'd have to change your code to something like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(...)
```

It's also advised to use `paramsMap` instead of `params`, which as its name describes will return a Map instead. So we can further change it to this:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => paramMap.get('id'))
```

Now we're using the `get` method on a map, pass it the key, in this case the name of your param and in the end, this'll basically give us the same result.

Another thing that is completely wrong with your code is the `map` operator. When working with Observables, we use the map operator, to mutate the data emitted. So for instance, this observable is emitting a Person. If you wanted just the person's name, you would use the map operator like this:

```
.map(person => person.name)
```

And if you're not used to this syntax, then this is equivalent:

```
.map(person => {return person.name})
```

The code that should run once you are receiving the desired data goes in the subscibe, which takes three arguments, but we usually only care about the first two, which are the success and error callback functions. Your final code should look something like this:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => 
    this._PersonService.getPerson(+params.get('id'))
        .subscribe((person) => this.person = person, () => {  //do something on error}))
```

Comment: Terminal throws an error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
For this line: this._PersonService.getPerson(params.get('id'))

Comment: +params.get('id')

Comment: That was my bad. The plus operator means different things but in this case it gives you the numeric value of something. The param retrieved with the get method will always be a string ('1'), and since we want to convert it to a number, we apply the plus operator.

Comment: It should also work, thnx! But it seems that my problem is that the "person" variable inside map (or in your variant - subscribe) function is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is asynchronous so you have to use pipe async to render it:

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Just add that pipe to interpolation and it will work.

Comment: I changed it to {{ (person|async)?.title }}, still not working

Comment: So, where to use the Pipe if not inside the interpolation?

Comment: I imported the Pipe into details.component.ts, right? And tried to use it as {{ 
person.name | async }}. Not working(

Comment: But do you have data in person? Let's do console log in detailscomponent in map function.

Comment: Hmm... person is undefined